# Can the styling of a JavaScript Alert be changed with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can the styling of a website message window be changed?

```js
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', e => {
    alert('Your clicked  Read More')
});
```

Comment: You can't do that

Comment: You need to use something like SweetAlert or any of the other custom message pop up codes out there.